# adb pull fold (10G, 9000+files)

Tags: android, adb

adb pull many many files

win10 android7.1 microUsb

```sh
┌[seair] [⚡]
└[C:\Windows\system32]> adb shell
QK1801:/ $ exit
┌[seair] [⚡]
└[C:\Windows\system32]> adb pull /storage/emulated/0/PixivPictures/ E:\Pictures\Phone
[  2%] /storage/emulated/0/PixivPictures/74591273_p0.jpeg: 53%
// 74591273_p0.jpeg is 20M size
```

when start, speed is fast. but once a file size is >=15M

it suspend and just wait, Transmission schedule not change.

I try adb pull many times, once a file size is >=15M, it suspend.

How deal with it ? ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this problem, BUT I may have some solutions.
For a single file, the following:

```
adb shell cat /sdcard/chex3.wad > chex3.wad
```

Then, download [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20) or similar hex editor, use it to open the file, and replace all hex `0D0D0A` with `0A`, then save.  (Search -> Replace... -> Hex-values)

I've done that on two binary files, one large, and the sha256 sums came out the same as pulling them.  (Also, I could open the image.)

If you want multiple files, try the following similar solution:

```
adb shell tar -c /sdcard/Documents > docs.tar
```

Do the same thing; replace all `0D0D0A` with `0A` as before, but then ALSO delete the following bytes, right at the beginning: `72 65 6D 6F 76 69 6E 67 20 6C 65 61 64 69 6E 67 20 27 2F 27 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 6D 65 6D 62 65 72 20 6E 61 6D 65 73 0A`, which looks like text `removing leading '/' from member names.`, but note that the final byte is a carriage return or something.  The file should then start immediately with the folder you tarred up, I think, such as `sdcard/Documents/`.  Save the file.

Now you should be able to extract the tar file with [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or whatever.

Note that since you're having problems transferring large files, it's still possible it will freeze.  But it's transferring things in a different way, so it also might not.